# Counterexample to "$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}=0$ implies $\lim_{t\to\infty} f'(t)=0$"

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

From [the previous question that I posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381660/fracftt-rightarrow-b-as-t-rightarrow-infty), it's true that $\lim_{t\to\infty} f'(t)=0$ implies $\lim_{t\to\infty}(\frac{f(t)}{t})=0$, but does anyone have a counterexample for the following false statement?

> $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}=0$ implies $\lim_{t\to\infty} f'(t)=0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's even possible to have $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}=0$ and $\limsup_{t\to\infty}f^{\prime}(t)=\infty$, as the example $f(t)=\sin(t^2)$ shows.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for instance take $f$ defined by $f(x)=\cos(x)$.

Comment: $f=cos$ is not correct

Comment: @Stu Why is that?

Comment: because he wants a counter example

Comment: @Stu And it **is** one.  $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\cos t}{t} = 0$, **but** $\cos' t = -\sin t \not\xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{} 0$.

Comment: oh sorry I thought it was $\frac{f'(t)}{t}$

Comment: @Stu Fair enough. I guess the downvote is no longer warranted, then.

Comment: @  Clement C it's locked

Comment: @Stu Oh. I honestly have no idea how these things work.

Comment: You need to make a minor edit. Just add one character save edit and then again delete the character and save. After this the downvote can be reversed if the downvoter desires. But yes this procedure is a bit irritating. +1 to compensate anyway.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks! Just had a go at it